# SQL Server performance - schema vs multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, ado.net, sql-server-2012

This is purely from performance standpoint and only for SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2012. I am migrating from a different database server (Ctree). The databases are from less than 100mbs to about 2-3GBs, five in total. There are a lot of tables - over 400 tables in all.

Would it be better in terms of performance only to use a single database and multiple schema or multiple databases as is? The existing logic is that there are multiple databases and there are 7 different applications (C# - ADO.NET) that use these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt you'll see any significant performance benefit from splitting this up into multiple databases, if those are all running on the same physical server machine in the end.

However: if you do split it up into several separate databases, you won't be able to establish referential integrity using foreign key constraints across database boundaries - so that might be a drawback and a negative point.

Comment: Foreign Key is not an issue. I am thinking the size of the database. The question really is - would the size of the single database be a factor in performance and how? The previous database design had five existing. So consolidating the separate databases into one will increase the size considerably.

Comment: @TejaswiRana: as I said - I don't think in terms of just **performance**, there's any benefit in splitting this up into several databases. As long as your write intelligent queries and you have the proper indexes in place - database size per se is absolutely negligable and doesn't play any significant role at all.